# Can I get an example please?

Tags: php, oop

```
$starcraft = array(  
    "drone" => array(   "cost" => "6_0-", 
                        "gas" => "192",
                        "minerals" => "33",
                        "attack" => "123",

                    )
    "zealot" => array(  "cost" => "5_0-", 
                        "gas" => "112",
                        "minerals" => "21",
                        "attack" => "321",
                    )               
)
```

I'm playing with oop and I want to display the information in this array using a class, but I don't know how to construct the class to display it.

This is what I have so far, and I don't know where to go from here. Am I supposed to use setters and getters?

```
class gamesInfo($game) {
    $unitname;
    $cost;
    $gas;
    $minerals;
    $attack;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking..

Comment: you're playing with classes and objects, not OOP. OOP is a complex ideology and philosophy. it's not enough to implement any class to say that your code follows OOP.

Comment: I see your problem. Drones cost 50 minerals and 0 gas, while Zealots cost 100 minerals and 0 gas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually pretty close so far.

In OOP, each object usually represents a discrete concept.  Therefore, a better name for your class would be `Unit` because it represents a unit in the game.  Example:

```
class Unit {
    var $name;
    var $cost;
    var $gas;
    var $minerals;
    var $attack;

    function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Note that this example has the appropriate instance variables (name, cost, etc) and a getter/setter pair for the name variable.  You'd want to add more getter/setter pairs for the other instance variables.

Once you have all your getter/setters, you can instantiate a `Unit` by doing this:

```
$zealot = new Unit();
$zealot->setName("Zealot");
$zealot->setAttack(321);
... etc.
```

You'll also want to learn about constructors, so that you can instantiate a `Unit` this way:

```
$zealot = new Unit("Zealot");
$zealot->setAttack(321);
```

You can see that a constructor would give you a bit of a shortcut there by letting you set the unit name at the same time you instantiate the `Unit` class.

So to print a `Unit` object, you'd do something like:

```
echo $zealot->getName();
```

**Edit:** Like zerkms said, OOP is complex, and what I described here is basically programming with classes and objects.  This is just the very beginning of OOP.

Comment: <snob_mode>i may be wrong, but answers to such kind of questions encourages further asking here questions that can be (and actually should be) simply answered by reading manual</snob_mode> ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why did not you start with http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php?